# Why can't I run xfce4-power-manager?

Tags: xfce, xfce4-power-manager

On my Compaq nc8000, I'm having a problem running `xfce4-power-manager`.

```
xfce4-power-manager
/usr/share/themes/Sonar-3.2/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:92: Murrine configuration option "gradients" is no longer supported and will be ignored.
/usr/share/themes/Sonar-3.2/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:147: Murrine configuration option "gradients" is no longer supported and will be ignored.
/usr/share/themes/Sonar-3.2/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:163: Murrine configuration option "gradients" is no longer supported and will be ignored.
/usr/share/themes/Sonar-3.2/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:167: Murrine configuration option "gradients" is no longer supported and will be ignored.
/usr/share/themes/Sonar-3.2/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:516: Murrine configuration option "gradients" is no longer supported and will be ignored.
rolandixor@nc8000-1:~$ xfce4-power-manager --debug
/usr/share/themes/Sonar-3.2/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:92: Murrine configuration option "gradients" is no longer supported and will be ignored.
/usr/share/themes/Sonar-3.2/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:147: Murrine configuration option "gradients" is no longer supported and will be ignored.
/usr/share/themes/Sonar-3.2/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:163: Murrine configuration option "gradients" is no longer supported and will be ignored.
/usr/share/themes/Sonar-3.2/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:167: Murrine configuration option "gradients" is no longer supported and will be ignored.
/usr/share/themes/Sonar-3.2/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:516: Murrine configuration option "gradients" is no longer supported and will be ignored.
TRACE[xfpm-main.c:200] xfpm_start(): Starting the power manager
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for general-notification
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for lock-screen-suspend-hibernate
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for power-save-on-battery
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for enable-cpu-freq-control
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for critical-power-level
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for show-brightness-popup
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for change-brightness-on-key-events
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for show-tray-icon
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for critical-power-action
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for hibernate-button-action
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for sleep-button-action
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for lid-action-on-ac
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for lid-action-on-battery
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for brightness-level-on-ac
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for brightness-level-on-battery
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for dpms-enabled
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for dpms-on-ac-sleep
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for dpms-on-ac-off
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for dpms-on-battery-sleep
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for dpms-on-battery-off
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for dpms-sleep-mode
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for inactivity-on-ac
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for inactivity-on-battery
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for inactivity-sleep-mode
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for brightness-on-ac
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for brightness-on-battery
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for spin-down-on-ac
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for spin-down-on-battery
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for spin-down-on-ac-timeout
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:156] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for spin-down-on-battery-timeout
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1053] xfpm_power_get_power_devices(): Power device detected at : /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_C136
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1053] xfpm_power_get_power_devices(): Power device detected at : /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_C139
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1011] xfpm_power_add_device(): Battery device detected at : /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_C139: ((XfpmDeviceType) XFPM_DEVICE_TYPE_BATTERY)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:179] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 124 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_POWER_OFF)

(xfce4-power-manager:7025): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: could not map keysym 1008ffa8 to keycode

TRACE[xfpm-button.c:179] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 213 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_HIBERNATE)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:179] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 150 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_SLEEP)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:179] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 233 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_MON_BRIGHTNESS_UP)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:179] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 232 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_MON_BRIGHTNESS_DOWN)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:179] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 244 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_BATTERY)
TRACE[xfpm-battery.c:148] xfpm_battery_refresh_visible(): visible=TRUE: ((XfpmShowIcon) SHOW_ICON_WHEN_BATTERY_PRESENT)
TRACE[xfpm-battery.c:284] xfpm_battery_refresh_icon(): Battery state 4
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1152] xfpm_power_refresh_adaptor_visible(): Tray icon configuration: : ((XfpmShowIcon) SHOW_ICON_WHEN_BATTERY_PRESENT)
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1117] xfpm_power_hide_adapter_icon(): Hide adaptor icon
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1053] xfpm_power_get_power_devices(): Power device detected at : /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_C138
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1011] xfpm_power_add_device(): Battery device detected at : /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_C138: ((XfpmDeviceType) XFPM_DEVICE_TYPE_BATTERY)
TRACE[xfpm-battery.c:284] xfpm_battery_refresh_icon(): Battery state 0
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1152] xfpm_power_refresh_adaptor_visible(): Tray icon configuration: : ((XfpmShowIcon) SHOW_ICON_WHEN_BATTERY_PRESENT)
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1117] xfpm_power_hide_adapter_icon(): Hide adaptor icon
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:369] xfpm_polkit_init_data(): Using unix session polkit subject
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:456] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.upower.suspend is authorized=TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:456] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate is authorized=TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1152] xfpm_power_refresh_adaptor_visible(): Tray icon configuration: : ((XfpmShowIcon) SHOW_ICON_WHEN_BATTERY_PRESENT)
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1117] xfpm_power_hide_adapter_icon(): Hide adaptor icon
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:456] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-set-spindown is authorized=TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-disks.c:170] xfpm_disks_get_is_auth_to_spin(): Is auth to spin down disks : 1
TRACE[xfpm-disks.c:147] xfpm_disks_set_spin_timeouts(): On Battery=0 spin_down_enabled=0 timeout=800

The program 'xfce4-power-manager' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadName (named color or font does not exist)'.
  (Details: serial 365 error_code 15 request_code 150 minor_code 11)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

What could be causing this, and how would I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-power-manager/+bug/821170). You can fix it by getting the package from 12.04 or by downloading the source and compiling it.

Seems to be a weird bug from beta1 that managed to get to release, it was fixed a few days ago but I am not sure the the package ever came to life in 11.10 repos, it is apparently in the proposed packages repo.